# SQL Case statement for checking a particular date format

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime, case

I have an Oracle table having col_date with different dates in it, i want to update my table based on below condition:

1. If col_date column has dates in 'MM/dd/yy' format then change the date to oracle date format as 'dd-MMM-yyyy' else update to null.

Tried below case condition:

```sql
select field1,
       field2,
       case
         when Check_Date_Input like to_date(Check_Date_Input,'MM/dd/yy')
           then date_format(to_date(Check_Date_Input, 'MM/dd/yy'), 'dd-MMM-yyyy')
         else null
       end as check_date
  from Table
```

This query updates the date field to null in all case. Please guide to write correct case condition.

Comment: Oracle DATE data-type does not have a format. Format is only used when converting DATE using the built-in functions TO_CHAR or TO_DATE. Oracle is not MySQL. You should remove the "mysql" tag from your question. Note that Oracle DATE data-type contains both a date and a time. LIKE operator is for use with CHAR or VARCHAR2 data types and not for DATE data-type.

Comment: This does exactly what you have written. Your else condition tells to return null in case the format mismatch. 2. Please tag only one database which you are using and currently it seems to be mixed up.

Comment: removed the tag, but my sql is not working for any format it updates to null value only.Can you help me out to fix the query

Comment: Nice..would it be possible to provide some sample data from the table with mixed format and how do you see the expected output.

Comment: What is the datatype of `check_date_input`? If it's varchar2 and you have a mix of `mm/dd/yy` and `dd/mm/yy` then you are really in trouble, because there is no way to tell which one it is when `dd` is less than 13.

Comment: @William, it is Oracle date datatype

Comment: In that case, it can have any display format you like, and I don't understand the problem. We can't store any preferred display format alongside a `date` value. The *storage* format is 7 bytes and is not particularly human-readable, e.g. the hex digits `78 78 0a 11 0a 2f 13` represent the time just now.

Comment: My problem statement is this- "If col_date column has dates in 'MM/dd/yy' format then change the date to oracle date format as 'dd-MMM-yyyy' else update to null. " This I have to achieve through SQL case statement.hope this is clear I am not worried about other things here.

Comment: "it is Oracle date datatype".  Then your entire assumption about 'format' is incorrect.  A DATE type _cannot_ have different formats.  It is always oracle's internal, binary format for DATE types.  What you "see" as different formats is a result of oracle converting its internal binary format into a character string for human consumption.  See https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Answer (score 2):

An Oracle date does not have specific format. It is stored in some internal format, that you don't really need to worry about. On the other hand, when *displaying* a date, Oracle builds a string representation of the date, that you are seeing in your output.

By default, the format is defined by nls parameter `nls_date_format`. You can change it to whatever you like by altering the database setting in your session, or by explicitely using `to_char()` in your query.

Say you want format `dd-mmm-yyyy`, then you can either do:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mm-yyyy';
```

And then run your query as:

```
select field1, field2, check_date_input from mytable
```

The nls setting remains acive for the life time of your session, so every `date` column will be displayed in that format in your resultsets.

Or, you can use `to_char()` within the query:

```
select field1, field2, to_char(check_date_input, 'dd-mm-yyyy') as check_date_input from mytable
```